# Issue with removing physics body from physics world (spritekit)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have one sprite and my code is:

```
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
sprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
sprite.physicsBody.mass = 550.0f;
sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1;
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1;
```

I can detect collision in:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    // destroy contact.bodyA , contact.bodyB
}
```

But how can I destroy/remove these bodies from physics world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand, but if you're looking for a way of removing your sprites upon collision, you have to access each physics body's node property, and call its removeFromParent function.

```
[contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
[contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
```

Of course, you'll want to add additional logic to determine whether the bit masks of the colliding sprites are the same as the ones you wish to destroy during collision.

Comment: and if you just want to remove the body but keep the sprite, simply use:  sprite.physicsBody = nil;